# Android: Session is restored when back is pressed twice

Tags: android, session, authentication

I am making a login app with android. Evrything is working fine but the problem is when the back button is pressed twice the session loggedout will be restored? Whatseems to be the problem

code snippet for logging out

```
public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();


        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        _context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Calling the logout method

```
btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Launching All products Activity
                        session.logoutUser();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });
```

Login code:

```
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            //System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
             String username = et.getText().toString().trim();
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
                  session.createLoginSession(username);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class));
                    }
                });


            }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Not Employee")){
                showAlertNotEmployee();
            }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Disabled")){
                showAlertDisabled();
            }else{
                showAlertNotFound();                
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlertNotFound(){
        Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }

    public void showAlertDisabled(){
        Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("Account Disabled.")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }

    public void showAlertNotEmployee(){
        Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("Employee Account Only")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding to the androidmanifest.xml in your Activity tags

```
 android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: wow that did it. could you explain what exactly does this code do?

Comment: That is making the os aware it needs to discard the activity once not in use..in case you want to do the same to fragments you popbackstack with the fragment manager

Comment: Hi I want to get back to you even though it's been weeks now. First I want to thank you again but i encountered a problem. Turns out the the session is killed even with a simple back command or switching apps. Apparently discarding the activity once not in use is not my desired result